# MS ACCESS SQL query needing multi-level grouping and Top 1 COUNT results

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max

I am creating a report. In the report, I am to summarize who is the night operator for the week. I receive the incorrect information when a substitute works the first day. I am attempting to count the number of days an operator works during the (SORTWEEK) at each (SITE). I'm struggling with how to select the correct operator for each site during each week. This is as close as I have come, but cannot get it to only show me the top record from each SITE each SORTWEEK. I know it has to do with the order of operations, but cannot figure out what I need to change.

```
SELECT [All].SORTWEEK, [All].SITE, [All].NOPER, COUNT([All].NOPER)
FROM [All]
GROUP BY [All].SORTWEEK, [All].SITE, [All].NOPER
ORDER BY [All].SORTWEEK, [All].SITE, COUNT(NOPER) DESC;
```

| SORTWEEK | SITE | NOPER | Cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/18/2023 | 18B | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 18B | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 1A | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 1A | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 1B | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 1B | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 2A2B | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 2A2B | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 3AB | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 3AB | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 3D | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 3D | ZACH | 2 |
| 1/18/2023 | 4AB | TODD | 5 |
| 1/18/2023 | 4AB | ZACH | 2 |

The list goes on, and most often there are only 2 names, but I would like the name of the person who put in the most days to show on the report.

Here's another failed attempt, but I don't understand the errors MSACCESS is throwing.

```
SELECT [All].SITE, [All].SORTWEEK, (SELECT TOP 1 NOPER FROM 
(SELECT [All].NOPER, COUNT([All].[NOPER])
    FROM [All] AS [Temp] 
    WHERE [Temp].[SITE] = [All].[SITE] 
    AND [All].[SORTWEEK] = [Temp].[SORTWEEK]
    ORDER BY COUNT([All].NOPER) DESC)) AS TOPNOP
FROM [All]
GROUP BY SORTWEEK, SITE, TOPNOP
ORDER BY [All].SITE, [All].SORTWEEK, [All].NOPER;
```

I can tell I am getting closer. The following query gives me the correct result after it prompts me for the SITE and SORTWEEK, but I can't get it to show all results.

```
SELECT [All].SITE, [All].SORTWEEK, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 NOPER FROM 
        (SELECT [All].NOPER, COUNT(NOPER)
        FROM [All]
        WHERE [Temp].SORTWEEK = [All].SORTWEEK
        AND [Temp].SITE = [All].SITE
        GROUP BY [All].SORTWEEK, [All].SITE, [All].NOPER
        ORDER BY COUNT([All].NOPER) DESC) 
    ) AS [#Temp]
FROM [All]
WHERE [Temp].SORTWEEK = [All].SORTWEEK
AND [Temp].SITE = [All].SITE
GROUP BY [All].SORTWEEK, [All].SITE
ORDER BY [All].SITE, [All].SORTWEEK;
```

Comment: Retrieving TOP 1 record for each group usually involves a subquery with TOP N syntax as attempted in your last version. Edit question to show expected output from the sample data. Advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: Prompts are for Temp.Sortweek and Temp.Site because Temp table/query is not known to the outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the posted dataset (a saved aggregate query object) named Temp as starting point, consider:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp WHERE NoPer IN (SELECT Top 1 NoPer FROM Temp AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.Sortweek = Temp.Sortweek AND Dupe.Site = Temp.Site ORDER BY Cnt DESC);
```

TODD is the top Cnt for each date/site pair.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is composed of two steps.  First, I get the shape of the grouped results and then lookup or calculate any remaining fields based on the group values.  This avoids the complexity of grouping and calculating at the same time.

Note: my ALL is the already grouped data you provided

Note: [ALL] is a reserved word and must be bracketed

[image]

```
SELECT [ALL].SORTWEEK, [ALL].SITE, Max([ALL].Cnt) AS BestCount
FROM [ALL]
GROUP BY [ALL].SORTWEEK, [ALL].SITE;

'results

----------------------------------------------------------------
|      SORTWEEK      |        SITE        |     BestCount      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 18B                |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 1A                 |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 1B                 |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 2A2B               |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 3AB                |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 3D                 |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 4AB                |                  5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Step 2 Calculate NOPER:

[image]

```
SELECT qrySORTWEEKSITE.SORTWEEK, qrySORTWEEKSITE.SITE, qrySORTWEEKSITE.BestCount, (SELECT TOP 1 NOPER FROM [ALL] WHERE (([ALL].[SORTWEEK] = [SORTWEEK]) AND ([ALL].[SITE]=[SITE]) AND ([ALL].[Cnt]=[BestCount]) )) AS NOPER
FROM qrySORTWEEKSITE;

'Results

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      SORTWEEK      |        SITE        |     BestCount      |       NOPER        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 18B                |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 1A                 |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 1B                 |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 2A2B               |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 3AB                |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 3D                 |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1/18/2023 | 4AB                |                  5 | TODD               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: make sure to scroll to see the full sql for calculating NOPER

Comment: Not sure why, but it's returning incorrect night operator. The count is correct and it's only the top result (count) showing, but the name displayed is incorrect.  On a side note, I can't figure out where/how to share my table data and combined query results to show what's happening with the code you provided me.  Thanks again for helping!!